# rspec controller test not working when trying to test for scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, endpoint

I have a controller method like so:

```
def count
  response = model.scope(params[:age])
  render json: {count: response.count}
end
```

Where the scope is supposed to query the table for the model with any records that have records with the specified age. The controller method works fine but writing the rspec test for it is not working.

I try to make some test data for the model like so:

```
let(:model) {create(:model, age:20) }
```

and then in my rspec test I try something like

```
 it  "calls endpoint and returns correct count" do
    get :method, params: {age:20}
    puts parsed_response
  end
```

I would assume that this test makes a get request to my endpoint with 20 as the age parameter. Since I made fake data for the model with one instance having age 20, I would assume the count would return 1 for the test. However it returns 0 when I view the parsed response in the puts. Is my undertsanding of how factory bot works incorrect? Am I testing the count incorrectly?

Comment: You're testing the model by exercising the controller. It would be better to first test the model itself, in a model spec, and then test the controller.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

Try changing from

`let(:model) {create(:model, age:20) }`

to

`let!(:model) {create(:model, age:20) }`

- when you create with let if you have not used that object/instance in the test case, the object never gets initiated/created in db.
- while let! creates the object immediately whether you use it or not.
  You can read about `let` and `let!` [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

#### Option 2

Usually I avoid using let!. Try changing your test case to

```
 it  "calls endpoint and returns correct count" do
    create(:model, age:20)
    get :method, params: {age:20}
    puts parsed_response
  end
```

Also, pro tip about debugging

```
def count
  p model.all <<<----- add this line to see what all records you have?

  response = model.scope(params[:age])
  render json: {count: response.count}
end
```